# Select distinct one field other first non empty or null

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have table

```
| Id  | val  |
| --- | ---- |
| 1   | null |
| 1   | qwe1 |
| 1   | qwe2 |
| 2   | null |
| 2   | qwe4 |
| 3   | qwe5 |
| 4   | qew6 |
| 4   | qwe7 |
| 5   | null |
| 5   | null |
```

is there any easy way to select distinct 'id' values with first non null 'val' values. if not exist then null. for example
result should be

```
| Id  | val  |
| --- | ---- |
| 1   | qwe1 |
| 2   | qwe4 |
| 3   | qwe5 |
| 4   | qew6 |
| 5   | null |
```

Comment: What do you consider "first" not null value? What do you sort by?

Comment: Have you tried a `group by`?

Comment: basically most important thing for me is 'val', i need to get 1 'val' for every distinct Id which is ANY not null value if exists, if not then null. It doesnt matter which 'val' col value it is. it can be random, but not null if possible. i am not sure how to ask more specific :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case a simple `GROUP BY` should be the solution:

```
  SELECT Id
        ,MIN(val) 
    FROM dbo.mytable
GROUP BY Id
```

Whenever using a `GROUP BY`, you have to use an aggregate function on all columns, which are not listed in the `GROUP BY`.
If an Id has a value (val) other than `NULL`, this value will be returned. 
 
If there are just `NULLs` for the Id, `NULL` will be returned.
As far as i unterstood (regarding your comment), this is exactly what you're going to approach.

If you always want to have *"the first"* value <> `NULL`, you'll need another sort criteria (like a timestamp column) and might be able to solve it with a `WINDOW-function`.

Comment: Oh thanks. Its actually the way to do it. Somehow i thought it should be more complicated thing

Comment: happens to me all the time too^^

Answer (score 1):

If you want the *first* non-`NULL` value (where "first" is based on `id`), then `MIN()` doesn't quite do it.  Window functions do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                 order by (case when val is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                                          id
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43f38/9)

> ```
> Create Table from SQL Fiddle:
> ```

CREATE TABLE tab1(pid integer, id  integer, val varchar(25))

> ```
> Insert dummy records :
> ```

```
 insert into tab1 
    values (1, 1   , null),
    (2, 1   , 'qwe1' ),
    (3, 1   , 'qwe2'),
    (4, 2   , null ),
    (5, 2   , 'qwe4' ),
    (6, 3   , 'qwe5' ),
    (7, 4   , 'qew6' ),
    (8, 4   , 'qwe7' ),
    (9, 5   , null ),
    (10, 5   , null );
```

> ```
> fire below query:
> ```

```
SELECT Id  ,MIN(val) as val  FROM tab1  GROUP BY Id;
```